# solve the following differentiation equations.

Tags: calculus

Please solve the following differential equation:

A)$$\frac{d y} {dx} + \frac{1}{t}y=3 \cos(2t)$$

here is my method: writing equation in form of the $y' + p(t)y=g(t)$ and I have difficulty with doing the rest of the calculation...

B)$$(1+t^2)\,y'+4\,t\,y'=(1+(t^2)^{-2})$$

C)$$t\,y' + 2\,y=\sin t$$

Comment: I take it you mean $dy/dt$, not $dy/dx$?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you mean $dy/dt$.  Theequation may be written as follows

$$t y' + y = 3 t \cos{2 t}$$

or

$$\frac{d}{dt} (t y) = 3 t \cos{2 t}$$

so that

$$t y(t) = 3 \int dt \, t \, \cos{2 t} = \frac{3}{2} t \sin{2 t} - \frac{3}{2} \int dt \, \sin{2 t} $$

or

$$y(t) =  \frac{3}{2} \sin{2 t} + \frac{3}{4} \frac{\cos{2 t} + C}{t} $$